# In-App Purchase: separate download of purchased items from transaction

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm implementing In-App purchase with my server delivering the purchases in the form of zip files (not Apple server).

As downloadable files are quite big, 50Mb-500Mb I would like to let the user buy the items
and only when they want download and install the purchases.

So my implementation would be
By - Close Apple Transaction and Mark Item as Purchased - Trigger Download when you Want

Apple docs suggest you close transaction only after download completed:
I've been reading all Apple docs and I cannot see any specific comment about this saying that you must
close transaction only after download.

Am I going toward an Apple rejection?

Here the code: in case "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased" I call the method 
"completeTransaction" which is closing the transaction itself. My question is about the
method:
[self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

Can I move this download from here in later action ofter "finishTransaction"?

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
       switch (transaction.transactionState)
       {
           case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
               // [self completeTransaction:transaction];
               break;

           case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
               // [self failedTransaction:transaction];
               break;

           case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
               // [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
           default:
               break;
       }

    }
}



- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: This needs to be clarified you say "Apple docs suggest you close" and "I cannot see any specific comment about this saying that you must close" These two pparts contradict each other. The first part says you have found the doc

Comment: I mean that Apple dosnt say "you have to close the transaction" only after the download is done. But in code samples, WWDC videos they do the download before to close the transaction. In my scenario I'm selling a "button" to download the item, not the item itself. On the other and I cannot constrain the user to download immediatly huge amounts of data.

Comment: I've seen lots of people misspell 'separate', but never quite like that. :p